# Open CSS Menu OnLoad

Tags: javascript, css, menu, onload

This is my website: http://tinyurl.com/n9vous5

I need a way to have the "Products" tab open when the page loads.

Thanks for the help! :-D

Comment: you want it to go the products page or have the dropdown already dropped down when it loads?

Comment: I don’t really see what your actual problem is… do you mean that on page load (or actually when the `DOMContentLoaded` event fires) the element selectable by `li.item-with-ul:nth-child(3) > ul:nth-child(2)` gets the `show` class added which would be exactly what the mouseover event handler `return $(this).find(">ul").addClass("show").stop(!0, !0).slideDown(h.animationSpeed);` is doing?

Comment: I'd like the dropdown to already drop down when the page loads. And yes Xufox, I believe what you're saying is correct... though I'm not sure how to implement your suggestions into the code. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I mean with the information that you have given us it is really hard to help you out but this is a really "HACKY FIX" But you might want to check the url and make sure it is the home page or something so that it isn't open on every page but the code below will do what you want it to.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#flexnav ul').first().addClass('show');
});
```